# Retrieve Fetch Request from Managed Object Context

Tags: core-data, model, nsfetchrequest

I created a Fetch Request "MyRequest" in the visual editor for my Core Data Model (where you also can visually add Entities as well). Now that the fetch request is created, how can I retrieve the fetch request from the model so I can execute it?

In pseudo code, I'd like to do something like this:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithName:@"MyRequest" inManagedObjectContext:myManagedObjectContext];
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [myManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [self.managedObjectModel fetchRequestTemplateForName:@"MyRequest"];
```